# How to check multiple conditions without using a ton of if statements

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a tik tac toe game, and I wanted to make it so that instead of adding `if/elif statements` every turn I could instead check the number and replace the corresponding number with either an X or O.

```
tile_1 = "1"
tile_2 = "2"
tile_3 = "3"
tile_4 = "4"
tile_5 = "5"
tile_6 = "6"
tile_7 = "7"
tile_8 = "8"
tile_9 = "9"


divider = "-----"
play_board = tile_1 + "|" + tile_2 + "|" + tile_3
play_board_1 = tile_4 + "|" + tile_5 + "|" + tile_6
play_board_2 =  tile_7 + "|" + tile_8 + "|" + tile_9

def board():
  print(play_board)
  print(divider)
  print(play_board_1)
  print(divider)
  print(play_board_2)

board()
```

This is what I did for the board because I thought it was the cleanest looking code I could come up with. I don't know if this helps but it seemed fitting according to the reprex rule.

Comment: Maybe change all those `place_*` variables to a single list. Then you can just do something like `place_list[int(X_placement) - 1] = 'X'`

Comment: have a dictionary?

Comment: "the point where I have to place the X or O on the board" this is going to be highly dependent on how "the board" is being stored. If you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] we would be able to provide better help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Structural Pattern Matching](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/) starting from python 3.10

```
match X_placement:
    case "1":
        place_1 = "X"
    case "2":
        place_2 = "X"
    #and so on
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck using 3.8.2 in replit because the school Chromebook doesn't have python itself.

Comment: Ok! You have changed your question and bow it's not clear what your question is.